# Old iTunes library

Tags: itunes, recovery, library

My first Apple laptop broke. I have a new one now, but I'd had the old one for about 5-6 years and bought a lot of music.

Is there a way to access that library from my new computer? I don't use the email address that it's associated with because I can't remember the password, so I can't do the "forgot my password" because they'll send it to the email address that I can't remember the password for. If I take my laptop in to get it fixed, they usually say it'll wipe that computers contents out. Reading some of the answers from similar questions don't give me much hope. I am very computer illiterate and don't understand a lot of the suggestions using different software and apps and I don't know what DRM is.

Is my library salvageable?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you've bought a lot of music from the iTunes Store, but don't have access to the email address associated with your account there, correct? If that's the case, your best bet is to contact [Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/ca/support/itunes/account/) - assuming you can establish yourself as the account owner, they may be able to get you back into your account.

Once you have access to your iTunes Store account again, you can use it to [download previous purchases](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519) onto your new computer (the availability of previous purchases may vary depending on your location). Any music you had in your iTunes library that you did not purchase from the store will likely be lost, however.